# Jquery hover function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<p id="para"> This is a paragraph</p>
```

JS/Jquery

```
$("para").hover(function() {$(this).hide();}, function() {$(this).show();});
```

Now what i am trying to is when mouse is over the paragraph, the element should hide and when mouse leaves the element is should be visible again. However neither the paragraph is hiding and hence not appearing back. What's wrong here ?

Comment: Also, not sure that when you've hidden the item that you'll get the mouseout event, since the element will now be hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the **#** ID selector, having just "para" is looking for a tag `<para>` (which of course doesn't exist in this case.

```
$("#para")
```

On a side note, you typically want to have some sort of `div` (of a set size let's say) etc wrapped around a situation like this, and there is where the hover event is taken from, and the inner div shown. Makes it less "skippy".

Also if you do it with a div it can be done with CSS:

```
div:hover #para { display:block; }
```

[jsFiddle CSS example](http://jsfiddle.net/hPJK7/)

Comment: ahhh can't believe it, i always make this mistake and due to some unknown reason i keep doing it again. Well thanks for the help...

Answer (score 2):

You missed "#" for ID.

```
$("#para").hover(function() {$(this).hide();}, function() {$(this).show();});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the missing `#` as a typo in the OP.. your code is not going to work as desired.. because the mouse out will be triggered as the element is hidden.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/s8cpz/

Answer (score 0):

This code will never work. When you are hovering over it, it is supposed to vanish instantly, right? However, when it vanishes, the mouse is still over it, and thus the vanishing `p` will register it as a `mouseleave`, (all it sees is the cursor is separated from it, whether the cursor is the culprit, or is it itself, it doesn't care), effectively firing the `mouseleave` handler of the `hover`, and this will continue ad infinitum, leading to rapid blinking of the `p`. You can do `$("p").css({opacity',0.01})` instead of `$('p').hide()`. Check the problem with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function() { $("p").hide(); },10000);
$("#para").mouseleave(function() {alert('cool');}); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="para"> This is a paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Keep your mouse on the `p`, after 10 seconds, when the `p` vanishes, you will see the alert poping up, signifying the firing of the `mouseleave` handler.

Answer (score 0):

if you correct ('para') with ('#para') you can not get your goal because when you hide p tag immediately mouseout event activate and hide() method run and you p tag start blinking until mouse cursor over.
it
this some solution might helpful.

```
$("#body").hover(function(){
$("#para").css("visibility","hidden");},
            function() 
            {$("#para").css("visibility","visible");
            }
           ); ​

<div id="body">
  <p id="para"> This is a paragraph</p>
<div>​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/Cc6Ty/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you missed the **#**, second, when an element hides, its css display property changes to none, so it occupies no space on page, **so the mouse is not on it anymore**, and it will show up again. This creates an infinite loop of a sort. Errors like these are purely logical and at times will even crash older versions of browsers.